# React Router (Dom) v4 redirect to different route upon input enter key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect to new route when user presses enter on input field.
I have a Title and Search component that I want rendered on every page. 
I have found different use cases with using Redirect component, withRouter component, using context, and possibly passing history object to my Search component which is where the input field lives. Any help would be appreciated..

App.js (main component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Title from './Title';
import Search from './Search';
import Home from './Home';
import Movie from './Movie';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Title />
                <Search />
                <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                            <Route path='/movie' component={Movie} />
                        </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Search.js (input component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Search.css';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            // TODO redirect user to '/movie'
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" id="searchTitle" placeholder="Search for a movie" onChange={this.handleChange} onKeyPress={this.handleSubmit} value={this.state.input} />
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: The `Search` component needs access to the `history` object provided by React Router. You can use the [`withRouter` HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter). Give it the `Search` component then you'll have access to it. Then push a new url like you normally would.

Comment: So what I did was render `Search` component on each route (`Home` and `Movie`) in order to have access to history prop provided by `Route` component. Then instead of using `<Route path='/' component={Home}` I used `<Route path='/' render={() => <Home {...props} />} />`. Inside `Home` component I then had access to `this.props.history` and could push the route to redirect

Comment: Yea that's another way to do it. It requires the parent component to have the history object though.

Comment: My initial problem was trying to render `Search` outside of any route to have default components wherever the user went

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside your handleSubmit function try:

```
this.props.history.push('/movie'); // or whatever
```

edit:
you'll probably need to bind this as well

```
onKeyPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
```

and do this to the component you're passing into the route

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return <Home props={this.props} />
}
```

...

```
<Route ... component={HomePage} />
```

Comment: Try explicitly passing
    props={this.props} in on the route(s)

Comment: But the search component is not in a route..is there a way to render my 'title' and 'search' component in a route and show them by default on every route

Comment: Pass the props in to the components and deal with the search component inside of there

Comment: You might have to basically send the history prop straight through to the component you need it on

Comment: But if it is not in a route, how would it have access to router history?

Comment: You're ultimately going to access it through one of the components you pass in on your route right? You may have to define the component with the props and pass that in. I'm on mobile right now though can't get the syntax for you

Comment: An example would help out a lot, when you have time please

Comment: Home page = () => {
        return <Home props={this.props} />
    }

Then put HomePage or MoviePage or whatever as the component in the route

Comment: Thanks for all the help... I was trying to render Search component outside of route to have to a default for every page, but to solve my issue, I added to both route component renders, which seems repetitive, but works and solves my issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem and getting the same error when I try to push.

Comment: @Ozan are you explicitly passing the props to the search component as well as binding this?

Comment: @ZachHill I don't have a search component but a QuestionDo component. So here is the the thing there is a welcome message rendering with a false state and with a button click it leads to the question being true. When it is done form is submitted with postForm method which is supposed to push the route history as well but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

All other solutions I came across were outdated because of the new version.

Refer to [React Router V4 / Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md).

I have finally solved the problem by doing the following;

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

And then in my state I have declared 'submitted' as false.

```
postForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      submitted : true
    })
  }
```

When you are returning inside your render method it is going to check with your state and

```
render(){
    if (this.state.submitted) {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/done"/>
      )
    }
    return ( 
         something else... 
       )
```

I don't know if this is one of the good solutions but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here to get more information in your case https://gist.github.com/verticalgrain/195468e69f2ac88f3d9573d285b09764

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you